# Find $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=3\}\cap\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 2a^2 + 3 b^2=6\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Find $A \cap  B$, where
>
> $A=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=3\},\quad B=\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 2a^2 + 3 b^2=6\}$

I know that $(\sqrt{3},0)$ and $(-\sqrt{3},0)\in A \cap B$ so $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$, but how can I find all of elements of $A \cap B$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $A$ is a circle and $B$ is an ellipse. At most, they can intersect in $4$ points. If $(h,k) \in A \cap B$, then 
\begin{eqnarray}
h^2+k^2 & = 3\\
2h^2+3k^2 & = 6
\end{eqnarray} 
From this you get $k^2=0$ and $h^2=3$, so the intersection pts are $(\pm\sqrt{3},0)$ only.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Since $B$ is an ellipse with center $(0,0)$ and semi-minor axes $\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt2$ the only two points on $B$ with distance $\sqrt3$ from the origin are $(\pm\sqrt3,0)$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

An.option:

Ellipse $2x^2+3y^2=6$, or

$3(x^2+y^2) =6+x^2$.

With $d^2$ the (distance)$^2$ from the origin:

$d^2:= x^2+y^2= 2 +(1/3)x^2 \le 3$,

since  $|x| \le √3$ for points on the ellipse.

$d^2 = 3$ , for  $x = ^{+}_{-}√3$, else $d^2<3$, i.e

only $2$ points on the circle with $r^2=3$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Dima.Welcome, hope it helped.